# How to extract a portion of a URL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, parsing, substring, amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to extract only a certain portion of a string URL field in my query. I am doing this in Amazon Redshift. The query is very simple, essentially

```
SELECT email_id, url
FROM emailsends
WHERE date > '01-01-2023'
```

Pretty simple overall. In the URL, every one is basically structured as so:

```
https://www.example.com/489r9759t9t897987&utm_source=summer-mailer&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=summer-sale
```

What I want from the URL is to extract utm_source and utm_campaign. I'd like them to be their own fields, so my output would be something like this:

| email_id | url | utm_source | utm_campaign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | google.com/dmecm | summer-mailer | summer-sale |

Is there a simple way to do this within the query? Substring using positions of text doesn't really work because all URLs are of different length.I'd kind of need to start with &utm_source and end it after the next & where utm_medium begins, for instance. I'm just unsure how to properly extract and parse.

I have tried using the Substring function and different kinds of REGEX ie REGEX_SUBSTR. I am using DBVisualizer, which can be a bit limiting. I'd like to do this sort of simple and not have to create a temp table or something.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to get the entire parameter, and then `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract the part after `=`.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, 'utm_source=[^&]+'), '=', -1)
```

Comment: Would you know an equivalent for PostgreSQL. I apologize for not appropriately communicating this above

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230584/emulating-mysqls-substring-index-in-pgsql found by googling "postgresql substring_index"

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it as simple select query like this:

```
SELECT
    email_id,
    url,
    SUBSTRING(url, 'utm_source=([^&]*?|$)') AS utm_source,
    SUBSTRING(url, 'utm_campaign=([^&]*?|$)') AS utm_campaign
FROM
    emailsends;
```

The `SUBSTRING` function also accepts regular expressions.