# Trying to remove everything before an '@' symbol in MySql Email column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql data base with a 'user.email' field. I want to update the table to remove everything before the @ symbol so I am just left with a column of email domains. Can't seem to get me query to run. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You want to update the data or just query it? If you just want to query it, someone else  had an answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628138/how-to-select-domain-name-from-email-address

Answer (score 14):

Keep everything after '@'

```
UPDATE users SET email = SUBSTR(email,LOCATE('@',email) + 1)
WHERE LOCATE('@',email) > 0;
```

Keep everything starting '@'

```
UPDATE users SET email = SUBSTR(email,LOCATE('@',email))
WHERE LOCATE('@',email) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select right(email, charindex('@', reverse(email)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table name is USERS and has EMAIL as column

Before update your email column data would be like
aa@xyz.com
123@syz.com

```
update users SET email=replace(email,left(email, INSTR(email, '@')-1),'');
```

After update
xyz.com
syz.com

If you do not need the @ symbol in the domain then remove '-1' from the query

Answer (score 1):

try this first:

```
select (SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1)) from user
```

if its ok then update as:

```
update user set email = (SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1))
```