# How to get the domain name without '.com'?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, substring

```
SELECT substr(Emails, instr(Emails, '@')+1)
      FROM EmployeeEmails;
```

Returns

```
gmail.com
```

Do I need to concat to get:

```
gmail
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select domain name from email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628138/how-to-select-domain-name-from-email-address)

Comment: Email**s**??? Can the string contain multiple emails?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Just one email. Each record has one email for example, bob@gmail.com, kristina@yahoo.com. I'm trying to return gmail, yahoo etc

Comment: Okay. So you chose a bad column name suggesting a value would represent multiple emails rather than one. It would be better to name this column `email` as each record only contains one email in this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to extract the domain name:

```
select regexp_replace(emails, '^[^@]+@([^.]+)\..+$', '\1') from employeeemails;
```

This works for any email of the pattern `abcd@efgh.ijkl` .

The pattern:

- `^` start of the sting
- `[^@]+` 1 to n characters other than @
- `@` the at sign @
- `(` remember the following string
- `[^.]+` 1 to n characters other than the dot .
- `)` end of the string to remember
- `\.` a dot .
- `.+` 1 to n characters
- `$` end of the string
- `\1` the remembered string

And here is the old-fashioned way without `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
select substr(emails,
              instr(emails, '@') + 1, 
              instr(emails, '.', instr(emails, '@') + 1) - instr(emails, '@') - 1
             )
from employeeemails;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the old-fashioned way and also the new way.

Answer (score 2):

Check your relevant database query :

**Query(for MySQL)**

```
select (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(Emails, INSTR(Emails, '@') + 1),'.',1)) from EmployeeEmails;
```

**Query(For Sql Server):**

```
select SUBSTRING(Emails,(CHARINDEX('@',Emails)+1),1) from EmployeeEmails;
```

**Query(For Oracle)**

```
    select substr(Emails,instr(Emails,'@',1)+1) as domain
from EmployeeEmails;
```

Comment: This is the exact answer given in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting an error: 
ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING_INDEX": Invalid identifier.

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer! I used this: select substr(Emails, INSTR(Emails,'@',1) + 1, 5) from EmployeeEmails
to get the full domain. With 1,1 I just got the first initial 'g'. Is there a query that identifies when there is the .com?

Comment: @Lizzie, Check again my edited answer. I hope its  helps to you

Comment: @Angel Thank you for the quick response! The Query(For Oracle) returns with the SUBSTRING_INDEX: invalid identifier. Should I change it to LENGTH(SUBSTR(Emails, '.', -1)))))

Comment: @Lizzie, Sorry I have no my oracle server, so I cant test it. What is the problem.

Comment: @Angel No worries. I'm getting an error ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING_INDEX": invalid identifier.

Comment: @Lizzie, Check my answer

Comment: @Angel Thank you for the update! Unfortunately, it returns "gmail.com". I am trying to get "gmail". I cannot move this discussion to chat because my reputation is too low.

Comment: Lizzie, yup Sorry,  I cant help you more. Because have no oracle server so, I cant test them. Go with @Muhammad F. Musad and chanchal answer.

Comment: @Angel Thank you for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` with wild cards [see here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/welcome.html)

- underscore character ( _ ) for  any single character.
- percent sign character (%) for a string of zero or more characters.

  `SELECT email FROM emails
  WHERE email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%'`

This will ignore the following cases (simple version for valid emails):

- emails that have at least one character before the @
- emails that have at least two characters between @ and .
- emails that have at least two characters between . and the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this : -

```
declare @email sysname = 'testCode@gmail.com'
SELECT substring(@email, charindex('@',@email,0)+1 , (charindex('.',@email,0)-1 - charindex('@',@email,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@email,CHARINDEX('@',@email,0)+1, Len(@email)-CHARINDEX('@',@email,0)-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@email),0))
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.