# Select only the domain name from an email address

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the domain instead of the full e-mail address in my query for Domain_. In the statement below I select user_data. `Email_address`but that provides foo@bar.com instead of bar.com which isn't sufficient:

```
INSERT INTO user_orders
        (`User_ID`, `Order_Number`, `Customer_ID`, `Email_address`, `Domain_`)
SELECT 
       user_data.`User_ID`, order_data.`Order_Number`, user_data.`Customer_ID`, 
       user_data.`Email_address`, user_data.`Domain_` 
FROM user_data
INNER JOIN order_data ON order_data.User_ID = user_data.User_ID;
```

My understanding was SUBSTRING_INDEX(Email_address,'@',-1) as Domain_ would work so I tried:

```
INSERT INTO user_orders
         (`User_ID`, `Order_Number`, `Customer_ID`, `Email_address`, `Domain_`)
SELECT 
     user_data.`User_ID`, order_data.`Order_Number`, user_data.`Customer_ID`, user_data.`Email_address`,  
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(user_data.`Email_address`, INSTR(user_data.`Email_address`, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as user_data.`Domain_` 
FROM user_data
INNER JOIN order_data ON order_data.User_ID = user_data.User_ID;
```

but the query fails and provides a syntax error.

To help isolate it more for clarity this is what I'm doing differently:

```
(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(user_data.`Email_address`, INSTR(user_data.`Email_address`, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as user_data.`Domain_`
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm stuck.

> Error: INSERT INTO user_orders(`User_ID`, `Order_Number`, `Customer_ID`, `Email_address`, `Domain_`)
> select user_data.`User_ID`, order_data.`Order_Number`, user_data.`Customer_ID`, user_data.`Email_address`, (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(user_data.`Email_address`, INSTR(user_data.`Email_address`, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as user_data.`Domain_` FROM user_data
> INNER JOIN order_data on order_data.User_ID = user_data.User_ID;
> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`Domain_` FROM user_data
> INNER JOIN order_data on order_data.User_ID = user...' at line 2 */```

Comment: Tip: Focus on the domain problem first. This query has a *lot* more going on than that. Also please include the *exact* error you get.

Comment: It only gives me a 1064 error.

Comment: Again, *exact error*, the whole thing, not just some number. The numbers are not especially unique.

Comment: When battling syntax errors, delete stuff from your query until it works, then add back in incrementally until you get an error. This will give you a much smaller change to focus on.

Comment: updated the error

Comment: user_data.(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(Email_address, INSTR(Email_address, '@') + 1),'.',1)) yields an error but user_data.`Email_address` doesn't

Comment: You can't do stuff like `user_data.(...)`, that isn't a column. Can you rework this to do the simplest possible `SELECT` statement on your schema that does *only* `Email_address, domain` where `domain` is your troublesome `SUBSTR(...)` thing?

Comment: So how do I truncate the Email_address to just the domain in that select statement then?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628138/how-to-select-domain-name-from-email-address) work?

Comment: I still can't figure it out but I'll just move on thanks anyway

Comment: The last statement after your `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function is the culprit. You don't need `as user_data.Domain_`. You just have to change that to something like `as 'Domain_'`, with apostrophe (single quote) wrapping it instead of `backquotes`. Actually, in my opinion, you don't even need to assign alias `as ....` since this is an `INSERT` syntax.

Comment: By the way, were you going to return `bar.com` or just `bar` from ` foo@bar.com` ? Because your current function `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(INSTR()))` is returning `bar` only.